# Image variable based on link via overflow

Tags: javascript, html

basically, i have alot of image links, and i want these links to trigger a fixed overlap style but a unique image based on the image link clicked.

```
<img src="../Images/square 300/Drawing/angel face300.jpg" style='height: 300px; width: 300px;' onclick="imageurls(this, '../Images/A4/drawing/angel face.jpg')" />
```

^^one basic image link w/ onclick

```
<script>
function imageurls(elem, imgurl) {
    var y = document.createElement("DIV").style.width = "100%";
        y.class = "overlay-content"
    var x = document.createElement("IMG").style.width = "100%";
        x.setAttribute("src", imgurl);
        x.setAttribute("width", "900");
        x.setAttribute("height", "900");
        x.setAttribute("alt", "_blank");
        y.appendChild(x);
    document.getElementById("Imagediv").appendChild(y).style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("Imagediv").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>
```

^^ my java script, where the problem seems to be but im unsure what aspect of it is

```
<div id="Imagediv" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
</div>
```

all my css styling works perfectly, and if i just use the  document.get.element.... and remove the var x and y the overlay works.

Answer (score 1):

variable declaration was wrong .use like this

```
     var x = document.createElement("IMG")
     var y = document.createElement("DIV")
```

Apply the style after the variable declaration.

> ***remove the var x and y the overlay works.***
>
> Because the variable declaration was wrong so `attributes`  was not append into the newly created element

```js
function imageurls(elem, imgurl) {
    var y = document.createElement("DIV")
           y.style.width = "100%";
        y.class = "overlay-content"
    var x = document.createElement("IMG")
        x.style.width = "100%";
        x.setAttribute("src", imgurl);
        x.setAttribute("width", "900px");
        x.setAttribute("height", "900px");
        x.setAttribute("alt", "_blank");
            y.appendChild(x);
    document.getElementById("Imagediv").appendChild(y).style.width = "100%";

    console.log(document.getElementById('Imagediv').innerHTML)
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("Imagediv").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```html
<div id="Imagediv" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
</div>
<img src="../Images/square 300/Drawing/angel face300.jpg" style='height: 300px; width: 300px;' onclick="imageurls(this, '../Images/A4/drawing/angel face.jpg')" />
```

Comment: Have tried that and still the when i click the image it does nothing, the overlay doesnt even come up. Is there a better or easier what achieve what i want? as if i just use

..... document.getElementById("Imagediv").style.width = "100%" ....

the overlay comes up but obviously is just blank, is there a better way to put a variable image in?

Comment: see my updated answer .i was shown the `console.log` what append in html is correctly append

Comment: Thanks heaps, have managed to get it working :), but now itil load up the right img the 1st time then only that img regardless of the next one i click, any thoughts?